# Copying data from a MySQL table to another MySQL table not showing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a registration form that validates the account by sending a validation code to the email. Once the user receive the code in his email he must click the link to validate his account(I simulated this using the localhost). BTW, I have 2 database for the registered members and for the temporary members(these are the members that are waiting for validation).

When the validation code is processed and matched, the data from the temporary table will be copied to the registered members table, after the copying is done the user data from temporary table will deleted.

when I checked my updated database(registered members table) the ID column had incremented but the username, password and email field has no data. what is the problem here?

here is the website I'm following for the tutorial but I did some little tweaks
http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/24.html

localhost/validated_email.php?passkey=639900974e5fc25626af1a6ce5da8b01

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
ob_start();

//define a function for temporary database (temporary_members)
function temporary_members_db(){
    $host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db="forum_members";
    $db_table="temporary_members";

    //=======================connect to database
    mysql_connect("$host","$db_username","$db_password") or die("Could not connect to the database!");
    mysql_select_db("$db") or die("database not found!");
}

function members_db() {
    $host="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="";
    $db="forum_members";
    $db_table="members";

    //=======================connect to database
    mysql_connect("$host","$db_username","$db_password") or die("Could not connect to the database!");
    mysql_select_db("$db") or die("database not found!");
}


//connect to the temporary_member table
temporary_members_db();

$code = $_GET['passkey'];

//execute mysql query to check the validation code
$check_code = "SELECT `validation_code` FROM `temporary_members`";
$execute_code = mysql_query($check_code);
$result_code = mysql_num_rows($execute_code);

if ($result_code==1) {
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($execute_code);
    $username = $rows['username'];
    $password = $rows['password'];
    $email = $rows['email'];
    $table_members = "members";

    members_db();
    $copy_values = "INSERT INTO $table_members(username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    $execute_copy = mysql_query($copy_values);
}
else {
    echo "Wrong validation code";
}

if ($execute_copy) {
    echo "Your account has been activated!";

//delete data from the temporary_members
$table_temporary_members = "temporary_members";
$delete_data = "DELETE FROM $table_temporary_members WHERE validation_code = '$code'";
$execute_delete = mysql_query($delete_data);
}



ob_end_flush();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. you didn´t need to connect 2 times
......
2. use mysqli and not mysql, it´s deprecated

Comment: and you could use 
`if (!$execute_copy) {
    die('Ungültige Anfrage: ' . mysql_error());
}` .....to see if an error exists

Comment: I see. should study then mysqli. thanks!